Identify JST connector
I've dismantled something I'm hoping to extend the cable on.
There is a JST connector on each end of the existing cable, which appears to be a JST SH connector based on measurements, 1.0mm between the pins. However, visually when I google a 1mm 4pin connector, it looks very different to the one on the end of my wire.
I'm guessing I'm either measuring wrong or there are multiple types of SH or I'm simply looking at the wrong thing so any help would be appreciated.




But then if I google JST SH 4 pin they always seem to have these chunky wings which don't look like the connectors I have.


That is indeed a JST SH connector.
Part number SHR-04V-S-B
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SHR-04V-S-B/759868

But then if I google JST SH 4

Because you're finding sites that sell who-knows-what and call it "JST SH 4". If you look at authorized distributors of electronic components, you will see that an honest-to-goodness JST SHR-04V-S-B does look like yours.

{Source: Digikey}

Thanks very much for your help. Much appreciated

Turned out to be a Micro "JST MX 1.25 4Pin" I guess my callipers are not very good!

There is no such thing as a JST MX. I know that there are people who sell "JST MX" but they are not made by JST, or they are not "MX".

I'd worked that out naming wise when I couldn't google MX so I assumed MX might be short for molex possibly? I ended up buying various sizes to just trial and error it. https://www.adafruit.com/product/4722 isn't the one i bought but looks the same from the photos. Molex or picoblade comes up a lot with 1.25mm searches

I appreciate your help. It's a bit of a minefield navigating components for someone new to electronics!
